# Recreate QApplication after previous instance has been exited

Tags: c++, qt

Is is possible to create and use new QApplication instance after previous one has been exited?

Comment: Did you try with simple case ? I did and I am definitely able to do so. I use this to run test apps successively ... So I would say, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can create a new QApplication after the previous instance is destroyed. I verified this in Windows using PyQt4. The program below displays an empty windows. Upon closing the first window the first QApplication is destroyed and a second QApplication is created that then shows a second blank window. Note that I had problems without the `del app` statement. This would be equivalent to using `delete` on your QApplication in C++. Just make sure to allocate the QApplication instance on the heap instead of the stack.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
del app # force garbage collection of the first QApplication

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Is there a way I can render multiople URLs like this? http://blog.sitescraper.net/2010/06/scraping-javascript-webpages-in-python.html

Comment: That's a bit off topic. However, there is no need for multiple QApplication instances. Just create multiple web views.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question discusses that:

[Problems with Multiple QApplications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656891/problems-with-multiple-qapplications)

Instead of creating a new instance of QApplication, you could create a new thread with its own window, and treat that as you would of a different QApplication from within the single program.

Comment: I believe the other question has a subtle difference. It sounds like mgamer wants to only have one QApplication active at a time, but create a new one after the previous one is destroyed.

Comment: @Judge Maygarden - that is exactly what I try to achieve

Answer (score 0):

For who google for `Python`, This is worked with me fine

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a singleinstance of QApplication
    app = QApplication.instance()
    if not app:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```