# QT application Autostart --- in linux

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

I have developed an application in Qt and want it to start automatically and occupy my screen.
It have some pop-ups also. It is for controlling some relays across the network.

1. What should be the right procedure in Embedded linux to start Qt application automatically and occupy my screen on system boot?
2. Which is the best window manager to use for embedded linux?
3. Do I need display manager or desktop manager in this case? As I need single application to run?
4. Also this link confused me a bit. Is window manager inside desktop Enviroment?

   Are these desktop environment another name for desktop manager like KDE?
   http://www.engadget.com/2012/10/30/how-to-picking-a-window-manager-linux/
5. What if there are more than one application of Qt to run? But at startup I want one application to cover the screen?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can simply create a script to start your application and add it to /etc/init.d folder, for example: `/etc/init.d/S30myapp`, which includes:

```
#!/bin/sh
/etc/my_qt_app -qws &
```

Of course, do not forget to `chmod +x` them.

2-3) The most simple solution is to use Qt Windowing System (QWS). Check [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qt-embedded-running.html) for more technical details.

4) Taken from tags from *superuser*:

> **Desktop-environments**: Software that provides a graphical user
>   interface, with elements like icons, windows, toolbars, as well as
>   additional features. Popular examples include Gnome and KDE.
>
> A **window manager** takes care of the placement and appearance of windows
>   in a GUI-driven operating system. Sometimes, the term also refers to
>   plugins that extend this basic functionality.

I don't know your requirements, but usually only windows manger is used in embedded devices. But as I mentioned before, Qt has its own windows manager - QWS. Another widespread option is *X Server*.

5) In case you use QWS (or any other windows manager), you can start your initial application and maximize it to full screen, so it will be the only application visible. However, check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656891/problems-with-multiple-qapplications) for multiple concurrent applications using QWS.

Comment: thanks, but single application have some pop-ups ----- also, i have added point 4,5 to my post please try to answer them.

Comment: thanks.. also as per your previous suggestion for single application with with no pop-up ... i will try for frame bubber on QT

Comment: Actually I haven't done Qt on top of *X* so I', not sure if *X server* is enough or you need *X Window Manager* too. I just know it's an alternative.