# Multiple QApplication instances

Tags: c++, qt, singleton, qapplication

I'd like to know what are the implications (problems) of having multiple `QApplication`/`QCoreApplication` instances in the same process, and how to solve some issues regarding it.

The scenario is as follows: I'd like to make a wrapper on a open source third-party application in order to convert it into an embeddable widget as an optional plugin (the application consists basically on a single `QMainWindow`-based interface).

Such project heavily relies on a `QCoreApplication` derived class but basically because it is used as an already existing singleton. I'm able to modify the code (and I'll have to do so in order to expose the `QMainWindow` as an embeddable widget), although for the complexity of that project I cannot simply *remove* the parent class.

So, the final application will have its own `QApplication` (created on start) and then will optionally load the aforementioned plugin (thus creating the second `QCoreApplication`). Only the first (main) `QApplication` is used for events loop (`QCoreApplication::exec()`).

I'm aware of the facts that `QCoreApplication` is a singleton. In my tests, the singleton always points to the last created instance:

```
qDebug() << qApp;
auto app1 = new QApplication(argc, argv);
qDebug() << qApp;
auto app2 = new TheOtherQApplication(argc, argv);
qDebug() << qApp;
```

The output is

> QObject(0x0)
>
> QApplication(0x6f9400, name = "test")
>
> ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication: "there should be only one application object", file kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp, line 595
>
> TheOtherQApplication(0x2550dc0, name = "test")
>
> TheOtherQApplication(0x2550dc0, name = "test") TheOtherQApplication(0x2550dc0, name = "test")

As it can be seen, after the second `QApplication` is created it replaces the global instance. Is there any way to solve this? As the plugin is optional the obvious answer (loading the main `QApplication` on second place) is not a suitable option.

Also, are there any other implications of having multiple `QApplication` instances? Or are all related to the events loop (checked) and the singleton?

*Note: This is a project based on Qt 4.7 due to third-party dependencies not fully updated yet. It is planned to be migrated to the latest version in a year or so, but for the moment I have to deal with 4.7.*

---

BTW, I've already reviewed several related questions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656891/problems-with-multiple-qapplications) but that doesn't provide any useful information.

Comment: Are you really sure the only way to go is to have another `QCoreApplication` instance for your custom `MainWindow`? For me, this seems very hackish that almost any other way is preferable. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to me...

Comment: I know it is hackish, but the problem with the plugin is that the client wants to be able to take advantage of future updates of that code, so the idea is to modify as little as possible the external project (even make a pull-request in the future). On the other hand, that plugin is completely optional, so I cannot rely on its existence for the main `QApplication` :(

Comment: so, the plugin uses Qt but a user can include it in his application even if he is not using Qt?

Comment: No: both the plugin and the application are in Qt, but the plugin is optional, so I cannot use the `QApplication` of the plugin as the `QApplication` of the main executable, that's why I'm asking for its coexistence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, as far as I've been able to understand, using two or more `Q*Application`s (`QCoreApplication`, `QGuiApplication`, `QApplication`) implies:

1. An assert fails in debug mode when creating the second application (or more). No crashes in release mode.
2. Each instantiation of `Q*Application` updates the singleton (i.e., `qApp` will always point to the last instance).
3. Global attributes such as application name and version are transferred along instances and override former ones.
4. Any signal connected to a slot of a `Q*Application` calls the slot of the singleton, even if connected before creating the newest instances.
5. Only slots connected to signals of latest `Q*Application` will be called (they are not transferred to the new instance).
6. Translators are not transferred when new `Q*Application` instances are created.
7. If the last `Q*Application` is destroyed then the singleton becomes null (it does not fallback to the previous instance).

You can test these features using the following code and toggling `USE_TWO_QAPPS`:

```
#include <QtCore>

#define USE_TWO_QAPPS

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QTranslator tr1;

  QCoreApplication a1(argc, argv);
  a1.setApplicationName("a1");
  a1.installTranslator(&tr1);
  qDebug() << qApp << &a1;
  qDebug() << "a1.applicationName() =" << a1.applicationName();

  // qApp == &a1
  QObject::connect(&a1, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, []() {
    // point 5, never called with  Q*Application
    qDebug() << "Hello world from a1!";
  });
  QTimer::singleShot(2000, &a1, &QCoreApplication::quit); // as if connected to latest qApp, point 4

#ifdef USE_TWO_QAPPS
// if (true) { // uncomment to test point 7
  QCoreApplication a2(argc, argv);
  a2.setApplicationName("a2");
  qDebug() << qApp << &a1 << &a2; // test point 2
  qDebug() << "a2.applicationName() =" << a2.applicationName();
  qDebug() << "a1.applicationName() =" << a1.applicationName(); // as if called from qApp, point 3
  QObject::connect(&a2, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, []() {
    qDebug() << "Hello world from a2!";
  });
// } // uncomment to test point 7
#endif

  qDebug() << qApp->removeTranslator(&tr1); // false if the translator is not installed, point 6
  a1.installTranslator(&tr1); // it is installed in the latest instance (as if called from qApp)
  qDebug() << qApp->removeTranslator(&tr1);

  return qApp->exec();
}
```

**Results with one `Q*Application`**

> QCoreApplication(0xfafb74) QCoreApplication(0xfafb74)
>
> a1.applicationName() = "a1"
>
> true
>
> true
>
> Hello world from a1!

**Results with two `Q*Application`**

> QCoreApplication(0xbefb2c) QCoreApplication(0xbefb2c)
>
> a1.applicationName() = "a1"
>
> ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication: "there should be only one application object", file ########\qtbase\src\corelib\kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp, line 769
>
> QCoreApplication(0xbefb1c) QCoreApplication(0xbefb2c) QCoreApplication(0xbefb1c)
>
> a2.applicationName() = "a2"
>
> a1.applicationName() = "a2"
>
> false
>
> true
>
> Hello world from a2!

When testing point 7, `a2` is destroyed when quitting the `if` statement. In this case, every call to `Q*Application` methods done raises a warning and are not executed (they don't crash and no asserts are broken). It happens even when calling from the previous application: `a1.installTranslator(&tr1);`

> QApplication::installTranslator: Please instantiate the QApplication object first

*Note: tested using Visual Studio 2010. Qt versions are 4.7 and 5.6.1-1, both with identical results*

---

**UPDATE:** a cleaner code version for this answer is available in https://github.com/cbuchart/stackoverflow/blob/master/46304070-multiple-qapplication-instances/main.cpp

Following comments, this code also tests what happens when all `QApplication` objects are destroyed and then created again. Results: as expected nothing special occurs, no side effects seems to be present.

---

**Conclusion**

It seems possible to work with two or more `Q*Application` having in mind these points, being the more critical the fact that, when done on any but last `Q*Application`, connections to signals are lost and translators are not installed. Also, if the last instance is destroyed then no application is available, so you should take care of those cases (for example, if unloading a DLL that created the last instance).

Comment: Interesting. So, it looks like I could create/destroy multiple instances? I'm asking because I'd like to use QCoreApplication in some non-parallel unit tests.

Comment: @PaulKnopf I've tested removing the first `QApplication` before adding the second one and results are the same. I've uploaded a cleaner version to GitHub that implicitly tests the `QApplication` destruction.